# Using depend_on with stack

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

[The documentation for depends_on states](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on):

> There are several things to be aware of when using `depends_on`:
>
> - `depends_on` does not wait for `db` and `redis` to be “ready” before starting `web` - only until they have been started. If you need to wait
>   for a service to be ready, see [Controlling startup order](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) for more on
>   this problem and strategies for solving it.
> - The `depends_on` option is ignored when [deploying a stack in swarm mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stack_deploy/) with a version 3 Compose file.

So, does this mean when I'm using swarm mode and version 3 compose file to deploy it will ignore all conditions under depends_on? For example:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "python", "app.py"]
  db:
    image: postgres
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty correct, `swarm` as a orchestration will ignore the `depends_on`.

But for your scenario, `depends_on` is really not necessary as you already have `wait-for-it.sh` which have better control than `depends_on` to assure the start order.

> You can control the order of service startup and shutdown with the depends_on option. Compose always starts and stops containers in dependency order, where dependencies are determined by depends_on, links, volumes_from, and network_mode: "service:...".
>
> However, for startup Compose does not wait until a container is “ready” (whatever that means for your particular application) - only until it’s running. There’s a good reason for this.
>
> There are limitations to this first solution. For example, it doesn’t verify when a specific service is really ready.
>
> Alternatively, write your own wrapper script to perform a more application-specific health check. For example, you might want to wait until Postgres is ready to accept commands

Details see [Control startup and shutdown order in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/), so you no need `depends_on` in your solution.